# Encryption while working with the data on IOS Iphone and Ipad

Tags: iphone, ios4, cryptography

I'm creating an app in which the security is a critical matter. What concerns the incoming and outcoming TCP/IP connections I decided to use simply the HTTPS protocol. What about the data to be stored on the phone I thought to use some encryption like AES256 or something similiar. I wanna to ask. Should I also encrypt the data when I'm working with it in the program (handling variables) ? Which is the most secure way to write secure code ? Are there some ready Encryption libraries in the IOS or it's better to use mine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS SDK includes the CommonCrypto library which you can use for AES encryption, though you should probably read this first: [Why Isn't My Encryption.. Encrypting?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-isnt-my-encryption-encrypting.html)

Comment: Hello thank you for the answare..But my main concern is not only to Encrypt the data to send it out to the Net but how to keep it in memory while working with it.

Comment: Yes, I got that. But attacks on physical memory are very complicated and hard to pull off, so you shouldn't need to worry about them unless you're working with nuclear launch codes. As for protecting data that you might be storing on the flash drive, remember that your data is only as safe as your key. But my main point is, if you're working with sensitive data, hire a cryptographer or at the very least read a book on cryptography, end-to-end.